# Get path to USB device connected to android phone

Tags: java, android, usb

I need to get path to connected USB flash to my phone and just find file.
But, i have some problems.

1. My Manifest:

   > <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
   >
   > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION"/>
2. My BroadcastReceiver

   ```
   private final String TAG = "USBDevicesReceiver";
   UsbDevice usbDevice;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction());

       if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE")){
           if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) {
               Log.d(TAG, "connected");

               usbDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

               try {
                   String path = usbDevice.getDeviceName();
                   Log.d(TAG, path);
                   Toast.makeText(context, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   if (FindFile.isFileFound(path, "log.txt")) {
                       Toast.makeText(context, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(context, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               } catch (Exception ex){
                   Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

But usbDevice returns null on this moment: `usbDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);`

Comment: What do you mean by "android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" ?

Comment: @SushinPv uses-permission

Comment: Thanks for helping with edditing my post

Comment: There are only two permission available for reading and writing data to storage <<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: To get the path of the external storage you only need to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permisson

Comment: @SusinPv so that's the problem why it returns null?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() - This will return path to external sdcard

Comment: Add these lines and try <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />

Comment: Hmmm. I dont need sd card. I need to get path for connected USB device by OTG

Comment: add the above permission and try the same.

Comment: @SushinPv nope, doesn't help

Comment: @Никита Шаврин, Did you find the solution?